# Get data from Javascript button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm newbie in JavaScript. And I need to do something with JS.

I have a table contains data and button (someone had created it before, and I need to edit it).

[image]

Here are the codes for the button edit (icon pencil), I got this code by click on Inspect Element:

```
<button class="btn btn-mini" onclick="javascript:edit('adam','adam','0987','1990-05-21','m','hr','','2012-01-16','2','1','5','2|1374546642038,3|1369620482658,4|0,5|0,6|0','newbal');" href="#long" data-toggle="modal">
<i class="icon-pencil"></i>
</button>
```

I need to get the username ('adam') to run the query on PHP file such as:

```
select ltotal from leave where lapplicant='USERNAME';
```

Here are the codes for function.edit:

```
 function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){
        document.getElementById("frm").id.value=k7; document.getElementById("frm").name.value=a;
        document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b;
        document.getElementById("frm").emid.value=c;
        document.getElementById("frm").dob.value=d;
        setCheckedValue(document.forms['frm'].elements['gender'],e);
        document.getElementById("frm").job.value=f;
        document.getElementById("frm").info.value=g;
        document.getElementById("frm").datejoin.value=h;
        document.getElementById('locid').value=i;
        document.getElementById('deptid').value=m m;
        var myTemp = l;
        var mySplitResult = myTemp.split(",");
        for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
            cval = mySplitResult[i];
            myval = cval.split("|");
            val1 = myval[0];
            val2 = myval[1];
            document.getElementById('temp'+val1).value= val2;

        }
```

How to get the username from the Javascript?

Comment: @LupitaNoyra take a look at ajax for transferring data between the front and back end

Comment: May I get the link, DutGRIFF?

Comment: Try this -> http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289

Comment: you need to provide more info, like paste the data between form tags.

Comment: @LupitaNoyra I like to mention one more thing you also must check the js **`edit`** function I guess it already had the ajax mechanism

Comment: I just updated with include the edit function, Arif. Thank you.

Comment: There are many codes between form tags, Robin. What's data that I should paste? I'll paste it. Thank you.

Comment: If you put `alert(a);` as the first line inside the `edit` function, you'll get the username

Comment: then how to call a at query in php file?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, you can have a php script set up that executes the query from data in the url's query string, then do something like

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("GET", "http://yourSite.com/includes/query_script.php?" + document.getElementsById('elementID'), false);
xhr.send();
```

Then, xhr.response is the response of the query...

Comment: Then how to call the data that I need on PHP file, or in queryline? Thank you, sir.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to where you're confused.  the part of your code "document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b" sets the username.  If you need to do something else with it, use document.getElementById("frm").username.value.

Comment: "frm" is the name of form used to put the data, one of is b. I confused how to passing the username from edit function to php file. And call the username on php file.

Answer (score -2):

The way I understand from your code that it is calling a javascript function "edit"
check for the function edit() in your html file.
If that is the case your javascript function will look like

```
function edit (var username, var password,.......){
    //code for the function
 }
```

use the sent paramater and send it to your php function.

try this link [Javascript, php ajax to mysql](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Comment: Yes,Sir. There is a function edit, looks like : function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){...} Could you explain more about "use the sent paramater and send it to your php function", Sir? Thank you.